# genymotion crashes when downloading virtual devices on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, genymotion

Genymotion crashes when I try to download virtual devices in my Ubuntu 17. It just downloads 1 or 2 percents and suddenly crashes. I deleted the whole .genymobile folder but it didn't work. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Great to see you found a workaround! Can you share the last 30 lines of ~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is the license and it still exists using a new personal use user as well.

The last 30 lines of ~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log

`2018-04-06T02:01:12+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
2018-04-06T02:01:12+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion "2.12.0"
2018-04-06T02:01:12+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
2018-04-06T02:01:12+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
2018-04-06T02:01:13+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2018-04-06T02:01:13+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2018-04-06T02:01:17+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [warning] token error 11 "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license has expired Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN."
2018-04-06T02:01:17+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [warning] License validity reaches the minimum acceptable value.
2018-04-06T02:01:20+04:30 [:1494] [debug] ("/opt/genymobile/genymotion/player", "--vm-name", "Google Nexus 5X - 8.0 - API 26 - 1080x1920")
2018-04-06T02:01:21+04:30 [player:1494] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2018-04-06T02:01:23+04:30 [Genymotion:32719] [warning] ****  STOPPING GENYMOTION  ****
2018-04-08T19:50:12+04:30 [genymotion:19181] [warning] Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
2018-04-08T19:50:12+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2018-04-08T19:50:12+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
2018-04-08T19:50:12+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion "2.12.0"
2018-04-08T19:50:12+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
2018-04-08T19:50:12+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
2018-04-08T19:50:12+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2018-04-08T19:50:12+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2018-04-08T19:50:17+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [critical] Network error while retrieving JSON content:  0
2018-04-08T19:50:17+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [critical] [getGenymotionLastVersion] Bad request: "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
2018-04-08T19:50:17+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [critical] Unable to get last Genymotion version number from server:  0
2018-04-08T19:50:17+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] token error 11 "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license has expired Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN."
2018-04-08T19:50:17+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] [VBox] [getSavedHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" Interface is down
2018-04-08T19:50:19+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] License validity reaches the minimum acceptable value.
2018-04-08T20:04:50+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] License validity reaches the minimum acceptable value.
2018-04-08T20:04:55+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2018-04-08T20:04:55+04:30 [Genymotion:19181] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile`

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the .ova file from an other source and have pasted it to the ova folder in .genymobile and have created a new related device in genymotion. The device runs perfectly. But I still don't know why I can't download the .ova file from genymotion.